# How do I interact with elements in the background of a modal?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I interact with elements in the background of a modal. I added the code:

```
data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"
```

It removed the gray background and disabled closing the modal when clicking outside the modal window. But I still can't interact with the elements in the background.

What do I need to do to interact with the elements outside the modal.

Comment: You might be facing it with pointer-evnts i guess. Can you provide your css and html code so we can actually check whats the issue